# How to embed all forms from Entity to one?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-3.3

For example I have Entity:

```
AppBundle:Car:
- name
- color

Car:
name | color
Audi | red
BMW  | blue
Chevrolet | yellow
```

And I would like show in one form all records from database.

So I would like in one from:

```
| Audi | red |
| BMW  | blue |
| Chevrolet | yellow |
```

I know how to embed relations forms, but how to embeed the same form to one?

```
$car = new Car();
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($car)
            ->add('name', TextType::class)
            ->add('color', TextType::class)
            ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Save All'))
            ->getForm();
```

How to add in this form all entries (Car)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may not be the best answer, but you can try create an entity that will contain collection of "cars". And then follow this [instruction](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html)

The most important thing is that you will receive a "prototype" and then you will be able to recreating new elements in javascript